# Listview with images not displaying

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have created custom Listview that has to show images as a list but images are not getting displayed.
I have 6 Images with dimensions 400x100 i want them to display as rows in listview.
I cant able to find where exactly i went wrong. Please help me . Thanks in advance.
Main Activity source code.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  ListView list;

  Integer[] imageId = {
      R.drawable.image1,
      R.drawable.image2,
      R.drawable.image3,
      R.drawable.image4,
      R.drawable.image5,
      R.drawable.image6,
  };
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CustomList adapter = new
        CustomList(MainActivity.this,imageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                        int position, long id) {
                }
            });
  }
}
```

CustomList adapter

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<ImageView>{
private final Activity context;
private final Integer[] imageId;
public CustomList(Activity context, Integer[] imageId) {
super(context, R.layout.list_single);
this.context = context;
this.imageId = imageId;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
imageView.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
return rowView;
}
}
```

acitivity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ListView
       android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_single.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: You don't need a table, your ImageView in a LinearLayout in list_single.xml

Comment: it seems to be the table is the cause of image not found

Comment: Instead of table can i put linear layout with orientation vertical?

Comment: I removed table and added linear layout with orientation vertical but still images are not displaying

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove the `RelativeLayout` inside which your `ListView` is? If there is only the `ListView` in it it's not useful.

You can also try to set `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` to `match_parent`.

Did you also try to add something else in your list item (like a `TextView` with a mock value), to see if it is displayed?